# How can I "decouple" a state var from its value so that in certain operations the value no longer updates on state change?

Tags: reactjs, react-state, react-state-management

I am, just for fun, writing a simple paint program. It has a `<Canvas>` that creates `[color, setColor]` with `useState` and passes them to its children, a `<ColorSelector>` and a grid of `<Cell>`s. Clicking a color in the ColorSelector updates `color`, and clicking a Cell sets its background to `color`.

The problem is of course that when you click a different color in ColorSelector and it updates `color`, it cascades down and changes all the currently painted pixels to the new color too. Normally that's the point of state vars, so maybe state isn't what I actually want here.

How can I let Cells always know the current `color` value but, once applied, keep the background color unchanged until the next click?

Comment: Your cells will need an internal state `currentColor` which is what you should be binding to background. When clicking on cells, set `currentColor` to the value of `selectedColor` you pass from parent currently.

Answer (score 1):

maybe try to pass the new color in a deep copy if I understand what you mean to

Comment: I tried that earlier without success, but after playing around with the idea some more, this answer led me to the solution.

Initially, Cell had a boolean state var called `isPainted`, and on render if `isPainted` is true, it renders a `<CellContent color={color} ...>` (or `color.concat()` - didn't matter which), and CellContent would use that color when clicked.


I changed it so that instead of setting `isPainted` to `true`, I set it to `color.concat()` and    rendered `<CellContent color={isPainted}...>`, which worked.

Comment: UPDATE: turns out the actual solution is a little different. Will post an answer with more information shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Yonatan's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73012473/11584810) got me on the right track to find the solution.

**What I'd been doing:** As described in my comment there, each `<Cell>` had an `isPainted` boolean and rendered a `<CellContents>` child which got an `onClick` that sets `isPainted` to true, and a `className` that maps to the selected `color` iff `isPainted` is true. Written that way, it didn't matter if I used `color` or a copy with e.g. `color.concat()`. Either way, when `color` changed, the Cell rerendered and got the new color.

**What ended up working:**

I eliminated the boolean middle-man and made `onClick` set `isPainted` to `color` (don't even need to make a copy) and made CellContent use the value of `isPainted` (which I should probably rename now) directly to get its the className.

***Why it worked***

*I think this is what's going on, but encourage anyone more knowledgeable to chime in!*

Previously I had `if (isPainted) { className = color }` in the body of `Cell`, so  whenever a cell got re-rendered, its className would change. Now `color`is only accessed in event handlers, so now when a Cell is re-rendered, it gets new handlers that use the new colors, but they don't actually do anything until the associated event happens.

**Code**

Here's the complete working solution

*(NOTE: the state var I've been calling `color` has been renamed to `selectedColor`, and `isPainted` has been changed to `colorClass`)*

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import styled, { css, ThemeProps } from 'styled-components';

const CellContent = styled.div<{ selectedColor?: string; size?: string, theme?: ThemeProps<{ background?: string; primary?: string; selected?: string }> }>`
  width: ${({ size }) => size || '1vmin'};
  height: ${({ size }) => size || '1vmin'};
  border: thin solid white;

  background-color:  ${({ theme }) => theme.primary || 'lightgrey'};
  &:hover {
    background-color: ${({ selectedColor }) => selectedColor } ;
  }
  &.red {
    background-color: red;
  }
  &.blue {
    background-color: blue;
  }
`;

interface CellProps {
  selectedColor: string;
  painting: boolean;
  setPainting: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>;
}

const Cell = ({ selectedColor, painting, setPainting }: CellProps) => {
  const [colorClass, setColorClass] = useState('')
  const onMouseDown = () => setPainting(true);
  const onMouseUp = () => setPainting(false);;
  const onClick = () => setColorClass(selectedColor);
  const onMouseOver = () => {
    if (painting) {
      setColorClass(selectedColor);
    }
  }

  return <CellContent {...{selectedColor, className: colorClass, onClick, onMouseOver, onMouseDown, onMouseUp}} />
}
```

Comment: Note: there's one bug still in this code: the hover state is supposed to use the selected color but it instead uses the painted color. I'll edit the solution once I've figured that out.

Comment: UPDATE: it's just a css precedence thing. Hopefully there's a more elegant way to write it, but for now giving the color classes their own hover states works, like this:

```
  &.red {
    background-color: red;
    &:hover {
      background-color: ${({ selectedColor }) => selectedColor} ;
    }
  }
```